# Mule stored procedure fails when deployed

Tags: jdbc, mule, mule-studio

I have an example flow that "Selects" records by calling a stored procedure on an SqlServer 2008R2 express instance.

The flow works as expected within Mule Studio but when deployed to Mule standalone 3.4.0 the call fails with the error

> A result set was generated for update.(SQL Code: 0, SQL State: + null)

The driver used is Microsoft's sqljdbc4.0

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks

```
<mule xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc.xsd">
    <jdbc:mssql-data-source name="MS_SQL_Data_Source" user="test" password="test" url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx;databaseName=test" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc:connector name="JDBC"  validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="JDBC" transactionPerMessage="false" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source"/>
    <flow name="DBTestFlow1" doc:name="DBTestFlow1">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="SQL-Purge" repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="Starting test" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="IsOOh" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JDBC" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc:query key="IsOOh" value="CALL IsOOH(#[function:now],#[null])"/>
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="Query Result = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the CE JDBC transport. If this is correct then that is your problem.

The CE version can not handle resultsets in calls to stored procedures. See the Feature table in the JDBC Transport documentation [1].

The reason it works in MuleStudio is that for some reason it seems that studio uses the EE JDBC transport even when the CE runtime is selected. I have reported this as a issue [2].

You can also see in the JDBC transport code[3] see that for a SQL statement that begins with CALL will result in a update on the QueryRunner.

You should be able to override this by defining your own Sqlstatementstrategyfactory[4].

[1] http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference
[2] https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-3817
[3] https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/jdbc/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/jdbc/sqlstrategy/DefaultSqlStatementStrategyFactory.java
[4] http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Configuration+Reference

// Pontus

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but I cant see anywhere that specifies this. I can see "Ability to invoke stored procedures on outbound endpoints. Supports IN parameters but not OUT parameters." but a cant see anything specifying no support for result sets.

Comment: Yes it is true that this limitation is not that well documented. However looking at the code it seems that this is a conscious decision.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call apps.create_sales_Order(:p_header_rec_oper,:P_order_number,:P_ordered_date,:P_line_id,:p_flow_Status_code,:P_return_status)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="p_header_rec_oper" value="CREATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_order_number" type="INTEGER"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_ordered_date" type="DATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_line_id" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="p_flow_Status_code" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_return_status" type="VARCHAR"/>
            
</db:stored-procedure>
```

Sample syntax of procedure call